# Pygame program keeps getting stuck in while loop, don't know how to fix

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to write a snake game using the Pygame library. I already wrote the main version of the game that's playable and now I'm trying to write an autopilot for the snake using the [BFS algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search). I am using this function to return a path from the snake head to the food:

```
def returnpath(prev,src,end):
    key=end
    path=[]
    while True:
        next=prev.get(key)
        path.append(next)
        if next==src:
            path.reverse()
            path.append(end)
            return path
        key=next
```

This function is called in the driver function of the game and in the bfs algorithm function. The thing I'm focusing on right now is highlighting the path on the screen. The path is highlighted on the screen but, the game crashes after reaching the food and when stopping the program the console mentions "KeyboardInterrupt" and a line from the returnpath function. Most of the time the line is either `key=next`, `next=prev.append(key)`, or `path.append(next)`.

[Here](https://github.com/Velkycat/bfssnakegame/blob/main/bfssnek.py) is the code for the autopilot version of the snake (ignroe the weird direction lines in the bfs function, I will fix those in the future).

Thanks to anyone who helps me understand why the program keeps crashing.

Comment: It's because you empty out `prev`, so `next` is `None` forevermore.  You should `print(src)` at the beginning of `returnpath`, and `print(next)` after the `get` call.

Comment: I'm sorry if this question sounds dumb, but you mean prev is emptied in `returnpath`, right?

Comment: Yes; since that's the only function you showed us, I assumed you'd focus there.  The debug prints will make it more clear.

Comment: I don't fully understand the problem yet, but thanks for the help!

Comment: I haven't thought of using print(type()). It returns the info I already know, but thanks anyway!